# Infinite Loop C++ Using Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, infinite-loop

Infinite Loop

The program below works most of the time.  However, I notice that after using the loop several times, the program will go into an infinite loop instead of exiting the program when I press a key besides 1.  For example I can enter 1 to enter a new score and then press any other key to exit the program till about 3 iterations.  However, it tends to go into an infinite loop after the 3rd iteration instead of exiting the program when I press a key other than 1.  How can I resolve this tendency to enter an infinite loop?

```
#include<iostream> 

using namespace std;

//Print grade for the score
void printGrade(double score)
{ 
    if (score >= 90)
        cout << 'A';
    else if (score >= 80.0)
        cout << 'B';
    else if (score >= 70)
        cout << 'C';
    else if (score >= 60)
        cout << 'D';
    else
        cout << 'F';
}

int main()
{
    int answer;

    do
    {
        cout << "Enter a score: ";
        double num;
        cin >> num;

        cout << "\nThe grade is: ";
        printGrade(num);
        cout << "\n\n";

        cout << "Do you want to enter another score (Enter 1 for Yes)? ";
        cin >> answer;
    }
    while(answer == 1);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you considered just adding a statement that prints the value of "answer" at the end of the code block (right above 'while answer==1')?  That's usually a lot faster (and you'll learn something) rather than crowdsourcing a debug effort.

Answer (score 4):

If `cin` is waiting for input of a particular type, but the user enters something which cannot be parsed as that type, `cin` will be put into an error state. While `cin` is in this error state, all future input operations with `cin` will fail. The user will not be prompted for input, and the input variables will never change. So `answer` will never change from 1.

If you enter an integer other than 1, the loop should terminate. However, if you enter something that is not an integer, that will cause an infinite loop.

To clear an error, make a call to `cin.clear()`, but first you need to check if there was an error, and you also need to clear the input buffer so the same thing doesn't happen again.  Personally, I find the whole affair messy, and prefer to get all my user input via `std::getline`, which should only ever fail on stream termination.  Then I use string parsing/conversion routines to check if the input matches the types I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Always test your input *after* reading to see if the input was successful:

```
if (!(std::cin >> answer)) {
     std:cout << "failed to read input\n";
     break;
}
```

I *guess* that you stream goes into fail state an it won't do anything while `std::ios_base::failbit` is set. You can use `std::cin.clear()` to clear the state and `std::cin.ignore()` to ignore the next (and probably offending) character.

Answer (score 0):

Use `cin.ignore()` before `cin` to make it read right